# Django left join (only two models)

Tags: django, orm

I'm stack on it, please need your help.
I have two models and a want to select all (or filtered) fields from Channel and left join last_published video from Video model. Need good solution using django ORM.

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Video(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_created=False)
    embedurl = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+left+join

Comment: Can you show what is your expected result on some example?